# TypeScript onClick Expected 0 arguments, but got 1

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types

I am encountering `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.` error with TypeScript and I cannot define the argument correctly in my type interface.

`type IProps = { // how to specify the argument should be 1 }`

`onClick={() => changeTheme(!(theme === "dark"))}`

Comment: `changeTheme(isDark:boolean): void`

Comment: Are you trying to define the function signature for ```changeTheme```? You are not actually passing that function as a prop, you're wrapping it in an anonymous function with 0 arguments and a return value of whatever it returns, if anything. What is your current interface?

Comment: @ChrisB. My interface only defines a classes: string for the class props passed to the component. I am not very experienced with TS, how do I go about wrapping it with an anonymous function?

Comment: You already are. I'm confused about exactly what you're trying to set the type for, and where you are doing so. Is it the ```onClick``` handler or the ```changeFunction``` function?